# Run python with nodemon in docker compose run/debug configuration

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pycharm

Is there a way to set up a **python run/debug configuration** with docker compose in **PyCharm** that uses `nodemon` to start the script? I want to use `nodemon` for the hot reload functionality in my python code. I’ve managed to set up it working with docker compose/dockerfile and when I start the project with `docker compose up` everything works as intended with nodemon. But I would like to create a run/debug config that uses my docker compose file and nodemon.

So far I’ve created a new interpreter using docker compose following [this guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html). This works (using the debug with breakpoints and run) but there is no hot reload from nodemon. Is there a way to configure my configuration to use nodemon or some other way to use hot reload with the mentioned setup?

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


# Install Node.js and npm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs \
    npm                       

# Install nodemon globally
RUN npm install -g nodemon

RUN groupadd -g 999 python && \
    useradd -r -u 999 -g python python

RUN chown python:python /app

COPY --chown=python:python . .

USER 999
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE

RUN chmod +x src/queue_consumer.py

CMD ["nodemon", "--exec", "python", "src/queue_consumer.py"]
```

This is my run configuration in pycharm
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is!
install the [Docker plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7724-docker) from jetbrain marketplace.

after installation you should get a new option in edit configuration tab
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I already have the docker plugin, it seems its bundeld with my release of pycharm. What option in the menu are i looking for?